# Average of Numbers in a Loop

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

In my C Program, I want to get the average of the sum of numbers being entered until the program stops. What should I add to check the average? Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    int x;
    int sum = 0;
    int average;
    int testEOF;

    //Statements
    printf("Enter your numbers: <EOF> to stop.\n");
    do
    {
        testEOF = scanf("%d", &x);
        if (testEOF !=EOF)
            sum +=x;

    } while (testEOF !=EOF);

    printf ("\nTotal: %d\n", sum);
    printf ("\nAverage: %d\n", average);
    return 0;
    //main
}
```

Comment: Keep a count of the number of values entered.  Divide the sum by the count.

Comment: your last `printf` does not have the `;` , you will get error, corrected

Comment: better to declare `average` as `float` or `double`

Comment: What happens if the user enters `"twenty-three"`? (keep **Ctrl + c** handy)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, for that matter why only `"twenty-three"`, i can see that with any random `"abcd"`

Comment: Yes, yes, any thing that would cause a *matching-failure* in `scanf` will do.

Comment: `scanf(3)` returns the number of actual format descriptors decoded, so testing `if (scanf("%d", &something) == EOF)` is incorrect (mostly if `EOF` is defined as `-1`)

Answer (score 1):

1. As other people explained, you have to initialize `sum` and `count`, they are never given their initial values. No need to initialize `average` and `x` because you assign `sum/count` to `average` and users will assign any value to `x`.
2. You have to put everything you want your `if` statement to do in `{...}`. But you didn't. Your if statement only does `sum +=x` and does not work for `count++` and `average = sum / count`. So your program increases the value of `count` even after `EOF`. So you found `14/6` rather than `14/5`.
3. You checked `testEOF != EOF` twice. One is in the `if` statement, other is in `do-while`.

I put the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
    float x;
    float sum = 0;
    float count = 0;
    float average;
    float testEOF;
    printf("Enter your numbers: <EOF> to stop.\n");
    while(1){
        testEOF = scanf("%f", &x);
        if (testEOF ==EOF){
            break;
        }
        sum +=x;
        count++;
        average = sum / count;
    }

    printf ("\nTotal: %f\n", sum);
    printf ("\nAverage: %.2f\n", average);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi! How can I limit the numbers into positive numbers only?. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `if(x<=0.0) {printf(“Not a positive number”); continue;} ` after `scanf `.  And if my answer solves your problem, please accept my answer. :)

Comment: I suggest you to look at [break and continue statements in C](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-break-continue-statement)

Comment: Can you try to write `if(x <= 0.0) {printf("Not a positive number\n");continue;}` just after `if (testEOF == EOF){break;}`. So you have to check the sign of the number not before `EOF check` statement but after `EOF check` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want your output to be printed with decimal point you can do the following , in that case

for inputs like `0, 1, 1` the out would be `0.666667` otherwise it will be simply `0` ignoring the decimal part.

the `while` part can be optimized as suggested by @David C. Rankin

```
double sum = 0;
double average = 0;
unsigned int count = 0;
//Statements
printf("Enter your numbers: <EOF> to stop.\n");
do
{
    testEOF = scanf("%d", &x);
    if (testEOF != EOF)
    {
        sum += x;
        count++;
    }
} while (testEOF != EOF);

printf ("\nTotal: %f\n", sum);
average = sum / count;
printf ("\nAverage: %f\n", average);
```

Comment: Integer division, won't work if user inputs 0, 1, 1.

Comment: i dint see the type of `average`, just added code to divide

Comment: @TanveerBadar - so what you are saying is the original questioner didn't intend `int average;` (while I may agree, that is something to clarify before downvoting)

Comment: If you update your answer and explain the limitation caused by `int average;` and how you would fix it -- I'd vote for that. You may also want to refactor the loop as `while (scanf ("%d", &x) == 1) { /* do the count and sum * }` (you don't want to try and `sum` and `count` the result of the user entering `"cow"`)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
float x;
float sum;
float count;
float average;
float testEOF;

    //Statements
    printf("Enter your numbers: <EOF> to stop.\n");
    do
        {
        testEOF = scanf("%f", &x);
        if (testEOF !=EOF)
            sum +=x;
            count++;
            average = sum / count;
            } while (testEOF !=EOF);

        printf ("\nTotal: %f\n", sum);
        printf ("\nAverage: %.2f\n", average);
        return 0;
}
```

This is now almost correct. The only thing is that the number is not getting divided by the number of values entered.
Example:
2
3
3
3
3

Sum is 14
Average: 2.3 (should be 2.8)

This seems that count is being added by 1 every time I get the average.

Comment: You forgot to initialize `sum` and `count` to `0`, so their values are undefined.